# Which values are missing in SQL from a list?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of values, say `1,2,3,4,5,6`. I have a SQL table with a field storing these values but only three rows, say, `2,4,5`. What sort of query will return three rows `1,3,6` for me? (storing all six in another table and left join'ing is cheating.)

Comment: Storing all the values in a lookup table and joining is by far the best way to do this.

Comment: Please include the type of datasbase you are on, the table structure and the SQL query that is returning three rows.

Comment: You mean like an antijoin or a `NOT IN()` clause?

Comment: the answer that worked for me is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013475/select-that-returns-list-of-values-not-occurring-in-any-row#answer-27053607

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try using EXCEPT (similar to MINUS in Oracle):

```
(SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION 
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 4
UNION
SELECT 5
UNION
SELECT 6)
EXCEPT
(SELECT 2
 UNION
 SELECT 3
 UNION
 SELECT 4)
```

Or, more relevant to your example:

```
(SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION 
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 4
UNION
SELECT 5
UNION
SELECT 6)
EXCEPT
(SELECT Field FROM Table)
```

where Field contains 2, 4, and 5.

Comment: That's a great idea. Here's a slight modification, one that works even in MySQL: `SELECT missing.1 AS missing FROM test RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION  SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) x ON x.1 = test.foo WHERE foo IS NULL;`

Comment: Nice solution. For databases that support the `values` row constructor this could be shortened to `values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6) EXCEPT SELECT col FROM foo`

Comment: You mention that my query won't work on Oracle/DB2/Firebird -- would `SELECT missing.1 AS missing FROM test RIGHT JOIN (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6))...` work there?

Comment: @chx that doesn't work in MySQL, it gives `Unknown column 'missing.1' in 'field list'`

Comment: this works for MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013475/select-that-returns-list-of-values-not-occurring-in-any-row#answer-27053607

Answer (score 8):

You didn't state your DBMS, so this is the ANSI SQL Version:

```
with the_values (id) as ( 
  values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)
)
select v.id 
from the_values v
  left join the_real_table t on t.id = v.id
where t.id is null;
```

Comment: that CTE is ansi standard syntax?  Wild.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: yes it is. Since 2003 I think

Comment: Op said left joining is "cheating" whatever that means. Didn't know we were taking an exam. ;)

Comment: @samyi: actually it says "*storing in a temp table **and** left joining*" is cheating. But I'm not storing them in a temp table so the boolean expression is still true ;)

Comment: The syntax doesn't work in SQL Server 2008, but something similar does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes SQL Server does not support the `values` row constructor. You would need to use a `SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 ...`

Comment: I am a little torn on which answer to accept -- this is ANSI but doesn't work with MySQL and to get it working on SQL Server you need the `SELECT - UNION` construct and if you write that out then it's easier to `JOIN` on that construct without using `WITH`. Sounds like `WITH` is SQL'99 btw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324935/mysql-with-clause

Comment: @chx: the syntax works in PostgreSQL, HSQLDB, Teradata, Vertica and DB2. You should have mentioned that you are limited by MySQL in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that -- I need a solution that works on MySQL *and* a wide range of databases.

Comment: @chx: the accepted solution won't work on all databases either (e.g. Oracle, DB2, Firebird) as they don't allow a SELECT without a table.

Comment: Works on Postgres

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 2):

with Mysql 8 you can use JSON_TABLE and select table from JSON array of values

```
SELECT *
      FROM
     JSON_TABLE(
       '[1,2,3,4,5,6]',
       '$[*]' COLUMNS( id INT PATH '$' ERROR ON ERROR )
     ) as v
 left join the_real_table t on t.id = v.id
where t.id is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `not in` operator will do the check you want.

```
declare @allValues table (value int)
insert @allValues values (1)
insert @allValues values (2)
insert @allValues values (3)
insert @allValues values (4)
insert @allValues values (5)
insert @allValues values (6)

declare @someValues table (value int)
insert @someValues values (2)
insert @someValues values (4)
insert @someValues values (5)

select
    *
from
    @allValues
where
    value not in (select value from @someValues)
```

Another method which is probably faster, using joins:

```
select
    av.value
from
    @allValues av
    left join @someValues sv on (av.value = sv.value)
where
    sv.value is null
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not cheating if it does the job. Set up a temp table or table variable with all the possible rows, then use a WHERE NOT EXISTS or a LEFT OUTER JOIN combined with WHERE TableVariableID IS NULL.

Comment: It doesn't do the job for the simple reason that I don't have permissions to create a temporary table... What I have is basic select access to a very large table and an arbitrary list of a couple hundred external IDs and I need to figure out which ones don't have any entries in that table. (The list is coming from a completely external source -- if they don't exist in that table they don't exist at all in the db.) I ended up selecting out the ones that did exist and then using Excel and a tedious manual process.

Answer (score -3):

You could use a `NOT IN` clause.

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column NOT IN (2,4,5)
```